# Frame not expanding

Tags: python, tkinter

Maybe this is just how Tkinter works but Im unsure. Currently I have the Main window with three frames laid out next to each other. Frame ContainerFrame is a master, then characterFrame and planetFrame are placed inside the ContainerFrame. The issue is or what I would like to happen is that the frames would fill up a set area of the window regardless of whether or not their is data/ widgets in them.
Here is what I envision it to look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrWWz.jpg

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

MainWindow = Tk()
def mainWindow():
  MainWindow.option_add('*tearOff', False)
  MainWindow.title("Interface")
  MainWindow.geometry('800x600')
  menubar = Menu(MainWindow)
  MainWindow.config(menu = menubar)
  File = Menu(menubar)
  About = Menu(menubar)
  menubar.add_cascade(menu = File, label = "File")
  menubar.add_cascade(menu = About, label = "About")

def frameContainer():
  containerFrame = Frame(MainWindow)
  containerFrame.pack(anchor = "nw", side = "left", fill = "both", expand = False)
  scroller = Scrollbar(orient = "vertical")

  characterFrame = Frame(containerFrame, borderwidth="2", relief="sunken")
  characterFrame.pack(anchor = "nw", side = "left", expand = True)

  planetFrame =  Frame(containerFrame ,borderwidth="2", relief="sunken")
  planetFrame.pack(anchor = "nw", side = "right", expand = True)

  scroller = Scrollbar(orient = "vertical")
  scroller.pack(anchor = "e", side = "right", fill = "y", expand = False)

  characterLable = Button(characterFrame, text ="Characters")
  characterLable.pack()
  Label(characterFrame, text ="Test1").pack()
  Label(characterFrame, text ="Test2").pack()

  Label(planetFrame, text ="Test1").pack()
  Label(planetFrame, text ="Test2").pack()


mainWindow()
frameContainer()
MainWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Your question mentions two frames, your code has three frames, and the picture has an unknown number of frames. Maybe you can mention frames by name, or give the frames distinctive colors, or make sure the code and the picture have the same names for all of the frames.

Comment: @BryanOakley I do have three frames one as a root, the characterFrame = Character Window, planetFrame = Planet Window. I have the scroll implemented but not as a frame and the Menu bar wouldn't be a frame either.

Comment: Your question still isn't clear. You say _" three frames laid out next to each other"_, but then say you have a container with two frames. How can the two inner frames be "next" to the container?

Comment: In your picture, "planet window" is just a small rectangle. Is it supposed to be small, or is it supposed to fill the right side?

Comment: @BryanOakley , Maybe Im explaining  wrong or just my lack of knowledge or both. But I was under the impression I needed to use a Frame (containerFrame) and then Place Other frames inside it to get Scroll function as well as better placement for widgets. So i created  characterFrame & planetFrame inside the containerFrame. I have made a new mock up here https://i.imgur.com/FX6HodM.png . The idea was to have characterFrame show  a list of names on the left then a bit of a empty space and then planetFrame take up the right side. As well if maximized kept the same format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would use a frame to organize a widget with a scrollbar, but a frame is not scrollable. If you want to scroll an area containing other widgets the usual thing to do is to use a canvas.

Study this guide: [Tkinter Scrollbar Patterns](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm)

Pack can be difficult to use and the only way I have found to overcome this is to keep trying. It's usually easier to see what you are doing if you let the different frames have different bg colors. Also I've taken the liberty to change some of your variable names as they do not give a hint as to what they are or are too similar to other names, eg. `mainWindow` and `MainWindow`.

I have added some padding to some widgets to make it look better.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def create_main_window():
    root.option_add('*tearOff', False)
    root.title("Interface")
    root.geometry('400x300+800+50')

    menubar = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu = menubar)
    File = Menu(menubar)
    About = Menu(menubar)
    menubar.add_cascade(menu = File, label = "File")
    menubar.add_cascade(menu = About, label = "About")

def create_container_frame():
    container = Frame(root, bg='tan')
    container.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    scroller = Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical")
    scroller.pack(side="right", fill="y")

    characterFrame = Frame(container, bd=2, relief="sunken", bg='thistle')
    characterFrame.pack(side="left", fill='y', padx=(10,0), pady=10)

    character_button = Button(characterFrame, text ="Characters")
    character_button.pack(padx=10, pady=(10,0))
    Label(characterFrame, text ="Test1").pack()
    Label(characterFrame, text ="Test2").pack()

    planetFrame = Frame(container ,bd=2, relief="sunken", bg='khaki')
    planetFrame.pack(side="left", fill='both', expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

    Label(planetFrame, text="Test1").pack(pady=(10,0))
    Label(planetFrame, text="Test2").pack()

create_main_window()
create_container_frame()

root.mainloop()
```

Is this the layout you are aiming for?

Comment: Ty exactly what i was looking for.